# Extract specific fields from file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file contents like below

```
ALARM: 20190507   1 10:00:09.023000000 10:00:09.023000000 ABB < 50> @160 . "AB12345" 12345 - S . ".." "" "" "POSSIBLE DISK ISSUE (N-to-A) (VAMOS)" "POSSIBLE DISK ISSUE (Y-to-Y) (VAMOS) - At 10:00:09.023, VAR 10 crossed 90 AM at (Alarm number 1213456789). A list issues related to this alarm. See the attached CSV for details (Click 'Export Attachment' at the top of the screen).==20190507.diskissue_g-to-A.12345.Aaslmeer.IssueReferences.1.csv.gz,20190507.diskissue_g-to-A.12345.Aaslmeer.IssueIds.2.csv.gz,20190507.diskissue_g-to-A.12345.Aaslmeer.IssueList.3.csv.gz FIELD*K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR*false*FIELD*K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR*1*FIELD*K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR*0.010000000*FIELD*K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR*0.000000000*FIELD*K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR*00:00:10.000*FIELD*K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR*0.000000000*FIELD*K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-MATCH_MULTIPLE_TESTS-ARR*false*FIELD*K-EXCLUDE_DIFFERENT_ISSUERS-ARR*false*FIELD*N-CHILD-TYPE*CURRENT*FIELD*N-CHILD-NAME*TRAVEL CURRENT PC04052*FIELD*N-ALARM-TYPE*PRESENT*FIELD*N-OFF-APPLICATION*false*FIELD*N-CTC*27.110000000*FIELD*N-CTC-CU*ABC*FIELD*N-ISSUE-NUM*1240000551*FIELD*N-KNOR-DOWN*N/A*FIELD*N-TRIGGER-TIME-BID*08:27:25.791*FIELD*N-TRIGGER-TIME-ASK*08:27:24.796*FIELD*N-BEN-AVG-DAILY-VOLUME*576525.600000000*FIELD*SYSTEM-TIME*10:02:04.451686000" "" PresentTime

ALARM: 20190507   2 10:00:09.023000000 10:00:09.023000000 ABB < 50> @160 . "LP12345" 12345 - I . ".." "" "" "POSSIBLE DISK ISSUE (Y-to-Y) (CURRENT)" "POSSIBLE DISK ISSUE (Y-to-Y) (VAMOS) - At 10:00:09.023, var 90 crossed  (issue number 12434576589). See the attached CSV for details (Click 'Export Attachment' at the top of the screen).==20190507.diskissue_g-to-A.12345.Aaslmeer.TraderReferences.1.csv.gz,20190507.diskissue_g-to-A.12345.Aaslmeer.IssueIds.2.csv.gz,20190507.diskissue_g-to-A.12345.Aaslmeer.IssueList.3.csv.gz FIELD*K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR*false*FIELD*K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR*1*FIELD*K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR*0.010000000*FIELD*K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR*0.000000000*FIELD*K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR*00:00:10.000*FIELD*K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-PRESENT_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR*0.000000000*FIELD*K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL*N/A*FIELD*K-MATCH_MULTIPLE_TESTS-ARR*false*FIELD*K-EXCLUDE_DIFFERENT_CASES-ARR*false*FIELD*N-CHILD-TYPE*CURRENT*FIELD*N-CHILD-NAME*TRAVEL Savings PC04052*FIELD*N-ALARM-TYPE*PRESENT*FIELD*N-OFF-APPLICATION*false*FIELD*N-CTC*27.110000000*FIELD*N-CTC-CU*ABC*FIELD*N-ISSUE-NUM*1240000551*FIELD*N-KNOR-DOWN*N/A*FIELD*N-RAISED-TIME-BID*08:27:25.791*FIELD*N-RAISED-TIME-ASK*08:27:24.796*FIELD*N-GUN-AVG-DAILY-VOLUME*576525.600000000*FIELD*SYSTEM-TIME*10:02:04.451686000" "" PresentTime
```

**Required  output to be like below**

```
1,K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR,false
1,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR,1
1,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.010000000
1,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR,0.000000000
1,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL,N/A
1,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR,00:00:10.000
1,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.000000000
1,K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-MATCH_MULTIPLE_TESTS-ARR,false
1,K-EXCLUDE_DIFFERENT_ISSUERS-ARR,false
1,N-CHILD-TYPE,CURRENT
1,N-CHILD-NAME,TRAVEL CURRENT PC04052
1,N-ALARM-TYPE,PRESENT
1,N-OFF-APPLICATION,false
1,N-CTC,27.110000000
1,N-CTC-CU,ABC
1,N-ISSUE-NUM,1240000551
1,N-KNOR-DOWN,N/A
1,N-TRIGGER-TIME-BID,08:27:25.791
1,N-TRIGGER-TIME-ASK,08:27:24.796
1,N-BEN-AVG-DAILY-VOLUME,576525.600000000
1,SYSTEM-TIME,10:02:04.451686000
2,K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR,false
2,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR,1
2,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.010000000
2,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR,0.000000000
2,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL,N/A
2,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR,00:00:10.000
2,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-PRESENT_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.000000000
2,K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-MATCH_MULTIPLE_TESTS-ARR,false
2,K-EXCLUDE_DIFFERENT_CASES-ARR,false
2,N-CHILD-TYPE,CURRENT
2,N-CHILD-NAME,TRAVEL Savings PC04052
2,N-ALARM-TYPE,PRESENT
2,N-OFF-APPLICATION,false
2,N-CTC,27.110000000
2,N-CTC-CU,ABC
2,N-ISSUE-NUM,1240000551
2,N-KNOR-DOWN,N/A
2,N-RAISED-TIME-BID,08:27:25.791
2,N-RAISED-TIME-ASK,08:27:24.796
2,N-GUN-AVG-DAILY-VOLUME,576525.600000000
2,SYSTEM-TIME,10:02:04.451686000
```

with Below command, I am able to extract the values without field 3 on each line. But not sure how to proceed to add field 3 on each line to get the required output.

*Command Tried*

```
 zcat input.gz |sed 's/FIELD/\n/g' | grep '^\*' | sed
 's/^*//g;s/*/,/g;s/,$//g;s/" "" PresentTime//g'
```

Received output

```
K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR,false
K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR,1
K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.010000000
K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR,0.000000000
K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL,N/A
K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR,00:00:10.000
K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.000000000
K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
```

If it is possible with other languages like python also it is manageable.

note: Input file is a read-only file.

Comment: If you reduce your sample to where it outputs, say, 6 lines instead of 50 or whatever that is you'd probably get more people willing to try to understand it and help you create a script to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 while read i; do 
    LineNO=$(echo $i |awk '{print $3}'); 
    echo "$i" |  awk -F 'FIELD' -v a=$LineNO '{for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) print a$j}'| awk -F '[" *]' '{print $1","$2","$3}'; 
 done < input
```

for .gz file

```
gunzip < input.gz | while read i; do 
    LineNO=$(echo $i |awk '{print $3}'); 
    echo "$i" |  awk -F 'FIELD' -v a=$LineNO '{for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) print a$j}'| awk -F '[" *]' '{print $1","$2","$3}'; 
 done
```

- `gunzip` to read the file.
- `while` to read line by line.
- `LineNo` to save the line number.
- `FIELD` to split line with a delimiter.
- `for` to print from second column.
- `a` to print the LineNo.
- second `awk` to format the output with comma separator.

Comment: Thanks working, could you plz explain how it works

Comment: Don't do this as it's buggy and extremely inefficient. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for some of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NF {
    idx = $3
    sub(/.* FIELD\*/,"")
    sub(/" .*/,"")
    n = split($0,f,/[*]/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=3) {
        print idx, f[i], f[i+1]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1,K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR,false
1,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR,1
1,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.010000000
1,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR,0.000000000
1,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL,N/A
1,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR,00:00:10.000
1,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.000000000
1,K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
1,K-MATCH_MULTIPLE_TESTS-ARR,false
1,K-EXCLUDE_DIFFERENT_ISSUERS-ARR,false
1,N-CHILD-TYPE,CURRENT
1,N-CHILD-NAME,TRAVEL CURRENT PC04052
1,N-ALARM-TYPE,PRESENT
1,N-OFF-APPLICATION,false
1,N-CTC,27.110000000
1,N-CTC-CU,ABC
1,N-ISSUE-NUM,1240000551
1,N-KNOR-DOWN,N/A
1,N-TRIGGER-TIME-BID,08:27:25.791
1,N-TRIGGER-TIME-ASK,08:27:24.796
1,N-BEN-AVG-DAILY-VOLUME,576525.600000000
1,SYSTEM-TIME,10:02:04.451686000
2,K-ALLOW_PROPRIETARY_VAMOSS-ARR,false
2,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-ARR,1
2,K-MEMORY_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.010000000
2,K-CPU_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-ARR,0.000000000
2,K-VOLUME_LIMIT-VAL,N/A
2,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-ARR,00:00:10.000
2,K-TIME_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-PRESENT_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-ARR,0.000000000
2,K-PROCESSING_PERCENT_THRESHOLD-VAL,N/A
2,K-MATCH_MULTIPLE_TESTS-ARR,false
2,K-EXCLUDE_DIFFERENT_CASES-ARR,false
2,N-CHILD-TYPE,CURRENT
2,N-CHILD-NAME,TRAVEL Savings PC04052
2,N-ALARM-TYPE,PRESENT
2,N-OFF-APPLICATION,false
2,N-CTC,27.110000000
2,N-CTC-CU,ABC
2,N-ISSUE-NUM,1240000551
2,N-KNOR-DOWN,N/A
2,N-RAISED-TIME-BID,08:27:25.791
2,N-RAISED-TIME-ASK,08:27:24.796
2,N-GUN-AVG-DAILY-VOLUME,576525.600000000
2,SYSTEM-TIME,10:02:04.451686000
```